# MacOS Mojave rpcinfo not working

Tags: macos, mojave, nfs

[MacOS 10.14.1, NFS to Ubuntu16]

I'm setting up NFS between my Raspberry Pi3 running Ubuntu16 (Server) and my Macbook Pro (Client).  I have a basic setup that's working for anonymous mounts, but need to fix write permissions for user mounts.

I'm trying to use `rpcinfo` to gather information about what's going on, but on my Mac, `rpcinfo` isn't working, and returns the errors below:

```
user@client:[20:31]$ rpcinfo -p
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: rpcinfo: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Broken pipe

user@client:[20:31]$ rpcinfo
rpcinfo: RPCBPROC_DUMP failed for host localhost
rpcinfo: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Broken pipe
```

Other NFS tools, e.g. `nfsstat -m` work fine.

Any suggestions as to what may be broken and how to fix this problem?